# How to uncheck the radio buttons in group?

Tags: android, radio-group

I'm doing a quiz app I have a radio group with 4 radio buttons and I have one next button.

While displaying First question and answers its no problem in check..when user gives next, the radio group should uncheck. How to implement this?

when user select the option it should verify the answer is correct or incorrect. I have stored the correct answers in a array..When user toggle the options it shows error in toggle buttons. How to implement this?

> ```
>    btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
>             @Override
>             public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
>                 RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);
>                 String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
>                 switch(btn_practicerg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
>                 case R.id.RB1:
>                     if (btn_practice1.isChecked()){
>                         btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case R.id.RB2:
>                     if (btn_practice2.isChecked()){
>                         btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case R.id.RB3:
>                     if (btn_practice3.isChecked()){
>                         btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case R.id.RB4:
>                     if (btn_practice4.isChecked()){
>                         btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 }
>                 crrtans=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(crrtans));
>                 if (temp.equals(crrtans.get(l))){
>                 TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                 txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS CORRECT");   
>                 txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
>                }else{
>               TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>           txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + "is INCORRECT");
>           txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); 
>               }
>             }
>      });
>     Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
>     nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>     public void onClick(View v){
>          if (j == ques1.size() -1) {
>                 showAlert1();
>             }
>           else{ 
>             ++j;
>             ++num;
>             TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>             txtque.setText("Q" + num +ques1.get(j));
>                         }      
>          });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is inside your `public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)`
you are creating an instance of the checked radio button based on checkedId which can be null once you call `clearCheck`. The fact is once you call `clearCheck` on your radio group when the next button is clicked,the `onCheckedChanged` event gets fired and it gets a null checkedId. As a result you get a null radio button when you do this: `RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);`

**EDIT(Better explanation):**

Add this method to your class:

```
private void doProcessingWithRadioButton(int checkedId)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);
        String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
        switch(btn_practicerg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
        case R.id.RB1:
            if (btn_practice1.isChecked()){
                btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
                btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
                btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.RB2:
            if (btn_practice2.isChecked()){
                btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
                btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
                btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.RB3:
            if (btn_practice3.isChecked()){
                btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
                btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
                btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.RB4:
            if (btn_practice4.isChecked()){
                btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
                btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
                btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
        }
        crrtans=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(crrtans));
        if (temp.equals(crrtans.get(l))){
            TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
            txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS CORRECT");   
            txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
       }else{
          TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
          txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + "is INCORRECT");
          txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); 
       }
    }
```

Now change your code like this:

```
btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
            if(checkedId != -1)
            {
                doProcessingWithRadioButton(checkedId);
            }
        });
```

Hope this helped. Please don't forget to mark this as answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: What ? Really i cant understand your code...please guide me in another way..I want to uncheck the radio buttons while user click next button...

Comment: Look at your code,inside `onCheckedChanged` listener you are creating an instance of RadioButton which has been checked by `checkedId` So if your checkedId is null the RadioButton is null so the latter codes rise NullException. So before doing all these check if the checkedId is not null.For better readability I have encapsulated all your codes inside onCheckedChange and added this validation.

Comment: It shows these two error..The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null and     void is an invalid type for the variable doProcessingWithRadioButton

Comment: check now,if it doesn't work,give me the whole class.I will edit where it needs and send back to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869783/problems-in-radiobuttons see the link

Comment: if you don't mind can you send me the whole project?at `abdulmunim.buet@gmail.com` let me do this for you.I think there's a simple mistake.But as a newbie you are failing to trace.

Answer (score 0):

To clear all radio buttons, that is none of the radio buttons in the group to be checked use

```
clearCheck()
```

for example ur

```
radiogroupname.clearCheck();
```

Comment: It shows error.. E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.example.finalpractice.Question$LoadQuestions$1.onCheckedChanged(Question.java:236)
 E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:172)
 E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:166)
E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:205)