# Problems in radiobuttons

Tags: android, radio-button

I'm new to android..

I'm facing a problem with radio buttons..Please guide me.

I have a radio group. First time it displays its unchecked. when user select the option at first time, i didn't face any problem. In mean time i have a next button. when user click on next button the options are unchecked for second question. Like the way user goes by giving next for next question. It works fine up to 4 or 5 questions after that while going for next question it throws error. please guide me.... what im doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

> ```
>     btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
>             @Override
>             public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
>                 switch(btn_practicerg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
>                 case R.id.RB1:
>                     if (btn_practice1.isChecked()){
>                         btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case R.id.RB2:
>                     if (btn_practice2.isChecked()){
>                         btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case R.id.RB3:
>                     if (btn_practice3.isChecked()){
>                         btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case R.id.RB4:
>                     if (btn_practice4.isChecked()){
>                         btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>                         btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 }
>                 RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);
>                 String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
>                 crrtans=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(crrtans));
>                 if (temp.equals(crrtans.get(l))){
>                 TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                 txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS CORRECT");
>                        }else{
>                 TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>             txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + "is INCORRECT");
>                      }
>      });
>     Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
>     nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>     public void onClick(View v){ 
>          TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>          txtRadio.setText("Nothing is picked");
>          txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CCEEFF"));
>           if (j == ques1.size() -1) {
>                 showAlert1();
>             }
>           else{ 
>             ++j;
>             ++num;
>             TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>             txtque.setText("Q" + num +ques1.get(j));
>             btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>              btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>              btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>              btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>             ++k;
>             btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));
>             btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+1));
>             btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+2));
>             btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+3));
>           }
>          // btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>           //btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>          // btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>          // btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>           btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
>                     int selectedId = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
>                     RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);
>                     String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
>                     switch(btn_practicerg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
>                     case R.id.RB1:
>                         if (btn_practice1.isChecked()){
>                             btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>                             btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>                             btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>                         }
>                         break;
>                     case R.id.RB2:
>                         if (btn_practice2.isChecked()){
>                             btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>                             btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>                             btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>                         }
>                         break;
>                     case R.id.RB3:
>                         if (btn_practice3.isChecked()){
>                             btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>                             btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>                             btn_practice4.setChecked(false);
>                         }
>                         break;
>                     case R.id.RB4:
>                         if (btn_practice4.isChecked()){
>                             btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
>                             btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
>                             btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
>                         }
>                         break;
>                     }
>                     l++;
>         if (temp.equals(crrtans.get(l))){
>         TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); // line 407 
>         txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS CORRECT");
>                     }else{
>             TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>         txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS INCORRECT");
>                    }      
>          });
> ```

Logcat

```
       E/AndroidRuntime(597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       E/AndroidRuntime(597): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at 
     java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at   
     com.example.finalpractice.Question$LoadQuestions$2$1.onCheckedChanged(Question.java:407)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at 
     android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:172)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:52)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at 
     android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:342)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at 
     android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:127)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at 
     android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:72)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at 
     android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at 
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at 
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
       E/AndroidRuntime(597):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @avadhani see my stacktrace

Comment: @androiduser see my stacktrace

Comment: Please any one guide me..really i don't know what im doing wrong..  why its throw error in 4 or 5th questions while going next...

Comment: @grishu please guide me what im missing..

Comment: Please post some more code if possible.

Comment: @grishu what else code you need..

Comment: @OneManArmy : where is Question.java:407 line

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K see in my code line 407

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have `IndexArrayOfBounds` in this line

```
answ1.get((k*4)+0)
```

because first you increase `k` and the use and arrays starts from `0`.

Comment: If i didn't code this line it works fine..but it won't uncheck... btn_practice1.setChecked(false);
             btn_practice2.setChecked(false);
             btn_practice3.setChecked(false);
             btn_practice4.setChecked(false);

Comment: Maybe in some question you have less then 4 answers?

Comment: i verified, there are four options available. really don't know why the error throws, if i didn't code .setChecked(false)...it works fine.. without unchecked..